# button that dynamically creates a new item list when clicked

Tags: java, android

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx8aV.jpg)

Sup guys, I've been programming for about a day and I'm struggling trying to find the answer to this question.

Can I create a button that dynamically creates a new item list when clicked?

Button = "Nova matéria" meaning "new subject" in english

And when that button is clicked, it would create a new item list (orange). Would that be possible? If so, how?

I'm using Android Studio

I tried making a button that when it's clicked, it would create a new string, and that new string would create an item inside a group. But apparently:

"In Android development, resources like strings are compiled into your APK file at build time, and the res/values/strings.xml file is read-only at runtime. This means you cannot programmatically modify or create new strings in the strings.xml file at runtime."